# Slow defaults access for key ClientState warning on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, warnings

I'm getting a "Slow defaults access for key ClientState took 0.034635 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000" warning when testing my iOS app - it seems to occur intermittently.  I've tried to look around to see what it is about, but I'm not entirely sure! Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Judging by the wording I think it can be interpreted as "Your database is hella slow, fix it!"

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that the first Viewcontroller is taking to long to load.

I never got this message until adding a large background png to the first view controller which now exhibits the same behaviour but all the time. Take out the png and I did not get it on 5 loads.

Comment: I got the message only once, when I added a new framework to the project. My guess is that the delay resulted from copying the additional files to the device.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing same as depicus: first viewController loads too long.

In my case app starts by populating tableView from last saved CoreData. Right after that server tells me authorization has expired, I start re-auth and facebook login view comes on-screen - on top of tableView.

This is were I get that error. Without facebook login, everything is ok == fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

SMSidat - I had the same problem and was looking found forever.  I have an sqlite database and upon loading the vc that accessed the database it stated "slow defaults .....clientState took to long to load and all.

Try to remove Auto Layout from your nibs. Once I did that, no more "slow defaults...warning"!!  Even though this is from 3 years ago...Hope it can help someone out.

Here is a link to the tread that helped me out
[Slow UIViewController load time (slow ClientState warning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300381/slow-uiviewcontroller-load-time-slow-clientstate-warning)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is cause by the time it takes to load a view when you invoke it. Take my case for example. I had a TabBar app and in one of my tabs it was a gallery. I was calling the view but within the view I was fetching everything on the main thread (big no no)... obviously, User interaction was gone out the window and the app will lock until done. The phone will take its time to load the images and to present the view. Once I multi-threaded my application and the pictures loaded in the background no more warning. Hope that helps, I am not sure how this warning works underneath but that changing this things got rid of it. :)