# Slow UIViewController load time (slow ClientState warning)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

Since I converted an old app to iOS 6 I've started getting the following message in my console.

`WARNING: Slow defaults access for key ClientState took 0.023656 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000`

Other than updating my code from iOS 5 to iOS 6, I also switched over to auto-layout. I've run Instruments/Time Profiler and  the `rootViewController` in my appDelegate is the problem. Everytime I switch view controllers it sucks the vast major of the time, (regardless of whether I have to instantiate the view controller or re-using one which already exists).

```
window.rootViewController = myViewController;
```

I know what the method does superficially, but I'm not sure what happens under the covers... what would cause it to be slow now and what can I do to speed it up?

**EDIT:** I've tried taking my storyboard off auto-layout and the problem vanishes (of course my UI layout is in shambles). So the obvious conclusion is, it's something about auto-layout. I've probably just under 70 views all combined on the screen and the various constraints needed to lay them out. I have a hard time believing auto-layout is that much slower (from ~80ms with auto-layout turned off to ~1370ms with auto- layout turned on).

Comment: Weird warning never saw it before but do you use Core Data?

Comment: Nope. Just a couple fairly complicated view controllers on a single storyboard and some data object classes I serialize out. Since all the data (which isn't much) needed to remain resident in memory the entire time the app is running Core Data seemed like overkill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow defaults access for key ClientState warning on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873144/slow-defaults-access-for-key-clientstate-warning-on-ios)

Comment: @Peter It could be, but it had no real answers so I figured I'd try with more specific details on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Having 70 views on-screen sounds like a lot! My proposal is to **make it simpler** in some way:

- Do you REALLY need all 70 views at the same time?
- Check if all views need autolayout, remove it where-ever possible
- Can some views be replaced by graphics? I've used views e.g. for shadows, might have been images

Can you split storyBoard into several smaller ones e.g. one for login, details, edit mode etc. Part of the slowness might come from system having to deal with (too) big storyBoards.

Comment: 70 views is not trivial, but it's not huge either. Consider a table cell. You've got a background view, a content view, an image view, a label view, disclosure view, (possible more) and that's just the default cell. At standard cell height that's 10 rendered at the same time + the tableview, nav bar, title and a button. You've reached just under 60 views for an exceeding common UI. Auto layout is also storyboard based. I can't remove auto layout per view and I would really like to use it since has simplified my code significantly (got to remove at lot of `setFrame` code).

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a new project with 2 view controllers and test the switching speed.  Every iOS app has a window, a root view controller and a view controller.   The problem isn't likely to be as narrow and clear-cut as you may be hoping.  What does each view controller load?  Did you inspect the underlying code?  Does app delegate do anything on initialization or change of root view controller?

Comment: When you say "inspect the underlying code" could you please explain exactly what the underlying code is? While I know some of the obvious bits removing old view structure from window, adding the new one, running the various methods for those... none of those methods take significant time. For the code slow down, the method being called does nothing other than instantiate the view controller if it doesn't exist and set the `rootViewController`.